font-family: cursive outputs comic sans font CSS
In CSS, when I input "font-family: cursive" for an id, it outputs Comic Sans (h1 element)
I had an h1 selector and two classes for the element (coding tutorial idk why), and for the id i put in:
#article-title {
  font-family: cursive;
}

When I run the code it outputs the title in the Comic Sans font. I tried commenting out the rest of the selectors for the target element and it still set it to Comic Sans.

cursive is a generic font family, and browsers may use different default fonts for it. Comic Sans is often the default for cursive in some browsers.
Specify the cursive font
#article-title {
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', 'Brush Script MT', cursive; 
}

